# LeetCode: Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock II

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, array, complexity

https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-ii/

Please review for performance.

> Say you have an array for which the *i*-th element is the price of a
>   given stock on day i.
>
> Design an algorithm to find the maximum profit. You may complete as
>   many transactions as you like (i.e., buy one and sell one share of the
>   stock multiple times).
>
> Note: You may not engage in multiple transactions at the same time
>   (i.e., you must sell the stock before you buy again).
>
> ```
> Example 1:
>
> Input: [7,1,5,3,6,4]
> Output: 7
> Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 3 (price = 5), profit = 5-1 = 4.
>              Then buy on day 4 (price = 3) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-3 = 3.
> Example 2:
>
> Input: [1,2,3,4,5]
> Output: 4
> Explanation: Buy on day 1 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 5), profit = 5-1 = 4.
>              Note that you cannot buy on day 1, buy on day 2 and sell them later, as you are
>              engaging multiple transactions at the same time. You must sell before buying again.
> Example 3:
>
> Input: [7,6,4,3,1]
> Output: 0
> Explanation: In this case, no transaction is done, i.e. max profit = 0.
> ```

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/explore/featured/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/564/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class BestTimetoBuyandSellStockII
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void AnswerIs7()
        {
            int[] prices = {7, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4};
            Assert.AreEqual(7, MaxProfit(prices));
        }

        public int MaxProfit(int[] prices)
        {
            int max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < prices.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if (prices[i] < prices[i + 1])
                {
                    max += prices[i + 1] - prices[i];
                }
            }
            return max;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Performance

Your solution is a single pass with time complexity \$O(n)\$. It's a small variation of the [proposed solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-ii/solution/).

#### Conventions

- use `static` when no instance state/operations are used
- use a clear, non-abbreviated method name `CalculateMaximumProfit`
- always guard against bad user input in `public` methods
- prefer the use of `var` when the type is obvious when reading the code
- prefer whitespace between operands and operators `prices.Length - 1`
- clean up waisted whitespace (in this case, after the `return` statement)

applied to your code:

```
 public static int CalculateMaximumProfit(int[] prices)
 {
     prices = prices ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prices));
     var max = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < prices.Length - 1; i++)
     {
         if (prices[i] < prices[i + 1])
         {
             max += prices[i + 1] - prices[i];
         }
     }
     return max;
 }
```